# Can a COM Shared Addin for Office (non-VSTO) add custom events to the host application..?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, office-interop, office-addins

I'm well-versed in VBA, but still learning Visual Studio. I'm experimenting with a COM Shared Addin for Microsoft Access. But Access seems to have no application-level events of its own. Is it possible to extend the Access Application class to add custom events? For that matter, is it possible to extend *any* existing 3rd-party class at all?

I thought perhaps one of the Visual Studio component classes or PowerPacks could do it, like a FileSystemWatcher waits for file system activity. Perhapes there is one that watches for program activity? Also, I suppose there might be a way to do it with system API calls, but if so I'm not yet aware of it.

As a specific example, would it be possible to add DatabaseOpen() and DatabaseClose() events to Access, so an Add-In could respond to them to enable or dim its ribbon buttons?

Comment: That's not possible.

Comment: Thank you. If you'd like to add that as the answer to my question, I'll upvote it.